# Javascript date-fns more specific distanceInWords

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I'm using [distanceInWord](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.5/docs/distanceInWords) to know how many time there is between 2 dates. But it's not exactly what I want because I need to be more specific.

For example if I have this : `1 January 2019 15:00:00 and 1 January 2019 16:30:00`

Actually it returns `1 hour` with `distanceInWordStrict()` or `about 1 hour` with `distanceInWord()`.

So I need to get `1h30` for this.

How can I do to be more specific ? 1h30, 2h15, 3h45, 2 days and 5 hours etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `distanceInWord` according to docs, as it created for wide ranges and short result strings (`about 7 years` instead of `7 years, 4 months, 7 weeks, 3 days and 5 seconds`).
You can only force units in `distanceInWordStrict` - passing `{unit: 'm'}` as a third parameter will output `90 minutes`.

But you can get the difference between dates with any units and according to result - format as you'd like to. Something like this:

```
let result;

const date1 = '1 January 2019 15:00:00';
const date2 = '1 January 2019 16:30:00';

const minutes = Math.abs(differenceInMinutes(date1, date2));

if(minutes < 60) {
  result = distanceInWordsStrict(date1, date2, {unit: 'm'})
}
else {
  result = distanceInWordsStrict(date1, date2, {unit: 'h'});
  result = result.replace(/ hours?/, `h${minutes % 60}m`)
}
```

If you never go over hours, then this would be a simpler formatting approach:

```
const hours = Math.abs(differenceInHours(date1, date2);
result = `${hours}h${minutes % 60}m`;
```

Also, you could simply get the difference in milliseconds, create a date object from it and format in any way you like.

Note that if you'll have a difference more than a day it will be output with a number of hours. So the final solution mostly depends on your variety of possible ranges.

Comment: I think the max I can get is in month

Comment: So you should check is it less than a day - output in hours format, if more - days format and so on